# Extra Brace in JSON generation in Java

Tags: android, json

I am trying to generate the following JSON

```
     {
       "mobileTerminate" : {
        "message" : {
          "content" : "Hello",
            "type" : "text"
            },
             "destination" : {
              "address" : "12125551212"
          }
        }
      }
```

I have the following code:

```
                JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject mobileObject = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject messageObject = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject destinationObject = new JSONObject();


                try {
                    Log.d("AAA", "in json try");
                    //messageObject.put("message", "");
                    messageObject.put("content", "Hello");
                    messageObject.put("type", "text");
                    destinationObject.put("address", "12125551212");

                    jsonData.put("MobileTerminate", mobileObject.toString() );
                    jsonData.put("message", messageObject.toString());
                    jsonData.put("destination", destinationObject.toString());
               }
```

This generate the following JSON:

```
  {"MobileTerminate":"{}",
        "message":"
         {\"content\":\"Hello\",\"type\":\"text\"}",
          "destination":"
         {\"address\":\"12125551212\"}"}
```

Ignore the \ which are escapes. The generated JSON has a couple of issues:

```
        1. The extra } after MobileTerminate : {
        2. Are the commas legal?
```

How can I update the code to make the generated JSON similar to the original?

Answer (score 1):

Remove all `toString()` calls while creating your `JSONObject`:

```
jsonData.put("MobileTerminate", mobileObject );
jsonData.put("message", messageObjectg());
jsonData.put("destination", destinationObject);
```

If you need string representation then, once you added all elements you wanted, only call `toString()` on final `jsonData` object:

```
Log.d("Works", jsonData.toString());
```

**EDIT**

> The JSON should start as {MobileTerminate: { .... but instead it's {MobileTerminate : {}

It's because you did not put anything into `mobileObject` so it is simply empty. You need to add the content like this:

```
mobileObject.put("message", messageObjectg());
mobileObject.put("destination", destinationObject);    
jsonData.put("MobileTerminate", mobileObject );
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Removing the to string fixes the comma and " problem but does not fix the extra }. The JSON should start as {MobileTerminate: { .... but instead it's {MobileTerminate : {} ...

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject();
JSONObject mobileObject = new JSONObject();
JSONObject messageObject = new JSONObject();
JSONObject destinationObject = new JSONObject();
try {
    messageObject.put("content", "Hello");
    messageObject.put("type", "text");
    destinationObject.put("address", "12125551212");

    mobileObject.put("message", messageObject);
    mobileObject.put("destination", destinationObject);

    jsonData.put("mobileTerminate", mobileObject);
    Log.d("TAG", "@@@ json :"+jsonData);
}
catch (Exception e){}
```